# Trigger/Deploy CDK stack on some event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I have written a CDK stack which works fine from my local machine - with CDK synth and then CDK deploy.

Now, is there a way by which on some event - (Specifically - event when an item is added to DynamoDB), the CDK stack gets deployed.

I was thinking to create the CDK codebase as a container and run it as ECS task, but I doubt there should be some other better way.

Please advice on what alternative approach can be taken for this usecase.

Comment: I think you can use dynamodb streams which will run the lambda and then lambda will trigger the code pipeline with the CDK. This is the first thing that comes to my mind. I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to solve this.

Comment: CodePipeline (or just a single CodeDeploy task) seems like the most appropriate way to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds strange that you'd like to do that.

However, at the end of the day, aws-cdk is a program you can run from any supported environment, lambda included.

To execute an AWS CDK deploy command from a Node.js based AWS Lambda function, you can use the `child_process` module to spawn a child process that will run the command.

Here's an example code snippet that demonstrates how you can do this:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const deploy = spawn('cdk', ['deploy'], { stdio: 'inherit' });

  deploy.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
  });

  deploy.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    deploy.on('exit', (code) => {
      if (code === 0) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject(new Error(`child process exited with code ${code}`));
      }
    });
  });
};
```

In this example, the `spawn` function is used to start a new process with the `cdk deploy` command. The `stdio: 'inherit'` option is used to forward the standard input/output streams of the child process to the parent process (i.e., the Lambda function).

Please note that the lambda function will require correct IAM access rights to perform a deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I went ahead with Codepipeline approach. DynamoDB stream event triggers lambda which starts the code pipeline. Code pipeline pulls the latest CDK code from github repository and runs it.